# How to Access the custom column from auth_user table in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-login

I am able to access the Pre define column

```
(id, password, last_login,is_superuser, username, first_name, 
       last_name, email, is_staff, is_active, date_joined )
```

of `auth_user` table .

after that I added the new column `img_url` in `auth_user` table.

but from same code `request.user.img_url`  It is not accessing the value of `img_url` column .

How I can access `img_url` column ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices here:

1. You can either extend your existing user model
2. Or You can implement a custome user model

For first Option (Extending you existing model) You can do like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then use it like this:

```
u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
freds_department = u.employee.department
```

For second option (Custom User Model) You can do like:

Create a model in sample_app and give its reference in settings.py like:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'sample_app.MyUser'
```

For more information:

[Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/)